# how to display just top 10 of the search results

Tags: search

I am writing a livesearch using Ajax+PHP+MySQL. I have some question wish you guys help me out.
How can I display just the top 10 of the result when I type in the search box? below is the js code. thanks for helps in advance.

```
function showUser(eleID,str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should limit your search to 10 results in the PHP file when querying the database. Check [this](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) out.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do paging also, use a combination of LIMIT and OFFSET sql statements to help you.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Answer (score 0):

you should try thinking at the first step. I would require only the first 10 results from the begining, that means in MySQL. Use `LIMIT 10` in your mysql query and voila, you got only 10 results. And your scripts will be faster as well.